# Quartz problem with scheduler when running parallel tests

Tags: asp.net, testing, quartz.net

The error: `Quartz.SchedulerException : Scheduler with name 'DefaultQuartzScheduler'` already exists.
I guess web application factory is used N for N number of tests, while scheduler is being created that number of times.

Applying `[assembly: CollectionBehavior(DisableTestParallelization = true)]` to namespace works, but is a hack in my opinion. I am unable to pass any Scheduler instances when running ASP.NET DI.

This is part of my configuration of DI:

```
services.AddQuartz(options =>
{
    options.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
});

services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
{
    options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by removing all hosted services from my Application Factory.